# Customizing tradingview charting_library header

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, sass, tradingview-api

I've currently finished integrating tradingview library and did initial customization to some parts of the styling.

Current css below:

```
.chart-page .apply-common-tooltip, .chart-page .button.undo, .chart-page .button.redo,
.chart-page .symbol-edit-widget .symbol-edit-inputspacer input.symbol-edit {
    background: rgba(30,30,30,0.5) !important;
    /* background: blue !important; */
    border-color: #444 !important;
    color: #fff!important;
}
body, .chart-controls-bar, #footer-chart-panel{
    background-color: rgba(30,30,30,0.5) !important;
}
.chart-page .chart-container {
    background: none !important;
    border-color: #444 !important; 
}
.drawingToolbar-2CoOuCv8-{
    background-color: rgba(30,30,30,0.5);
}
.separator-3cgsM4c1-{
    background-color: #666;
}
a.button.getimage.apply-common-tooltip {
    background-color: #97999d !important;
}
```

What I want is to actually modify the chart's header panel, I couldn't seem to get the right mix of css to make it closer to the chart body and also reduce it's height without destroying the children.

Below is current screenshot with indicator of where I'd like to customize.
[image: THE YELLOW HIGHLIGHTED AREA is where I'd like to modify cleanly]

Answer (score 1):

You should to config new css file:

```
var tvChart= new TradingView.widget(option);
tvChart.onChartReady(function() {
    tvChart.addCustomCSSFile('css/my-custom-css.css')
})
```

and put your new style in "my-custom-css.css"

Answer (score 0):

light

```css
html.theme-light .group-wWM3zP_M- {
  background: #1E1E1F !important;
}
```

or dark

```css
html.theme-dark .group-wWM3zP_M- {
  background: #1E1E1F !important;
}
```